# How prevent the script stops? for 504 Gateway Timeout Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-4, timeout

I use https://github.com/ollieglass/share-counter

my script

```
posts.each do |pp|

    begin
      puts pp.post_link

      url = URI.parse("#{pp.post_link}")
      req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
      res = req.request_head(url.path)

      if res.code == "200"

        shared_social_count = ShareCounter.all "#{pp.post_link}"

        unless shared_social_count.blank?

          sd = SharedCount.find_or_create_by post_id: "#{pp.id}"

          sd.twitter = shared_social_count[:twitter]
          sd.facebook = shared_social_count[:facebook]
          sd.linkedin = shared_social_count[:linkedin]
          sd.googleplus = shared_social_count[:googleplus]

          sd.save

        end
      end
    rescue Exception => e
       puts "caught exception #{e}! ohnoes!"

      next

    end
  end
```

Works well a while but some news causes an error and stops the loop

```
http://www.prnoticias.com/index.php/comunicacion/1224-foro-mundial/20130612-la-asesora-del-papa-tambien-estara-en-la-wprf-
Failed 1 attempt(s) - 504 Gateway Timeout
Failed 2 attempt(s) - 504 Gateway Timeout
Failed 3 attempt(s) - 504 Gateway Timeout
rake aborted!
Exception: Exception
RestClient::GatewayTimeout: 504 Gateway Timeout
```

Know how to avoid not stop the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
if res.code == "504"
    next
    ## create any log entry to know this url return 504
end
```

this will capture the 504 error and skip to next value in array my suggestion move to sidekiq then it will be easier to manage this:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq